# How do I reduce the spacing between rows and force a specific column to have a narrower width?

Tags: tables

I am using this online tool https://www.latex-tables.com/# to generate my table. This is the code it generates for the table below. How can I reduce the spacing between each row and also how can I force specific columns shown by the red arrows below to have a smaller width? They were used mainly as separators between chunks of columns.

```
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tblr}{
  column{even} = {c},
  column{3} = {c},
  column{5} = {c},
  column{7} = {c},
  column{9} = {c},
  column{11} = {c},
  column{13} = {c},
  column{15} = {c},
  column{17} = {c},
  column{19} = {c},
  column{21} = {c},
  cell{1}{2} = {c=8}{},
  cell{1}{11} = {c=2}{},
  cell{1}{14} = {c=8}{},
  cell{2}{2} = {c=2}{},
  cell{2}{5} = {c=2}{},
  cell{2}{8} = {c=2}{},
  cell{2}{11} = {c=2}{},
  cell{2}{14} = {c=2}{},
  cell{2}{17} = {c=2}{},
  cell{2}{20} = {c=2}{},
  hline{1,10} = {-}{0.08em},
  hline{2} = {2-9,11-12,14-21}{},
  hline{3} = {2-3,5-6,8-9,11-12,14-15,17-18,20-21}{},
  hline{4,7-8} = {-}{},
}
          & x &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  & x &   &  &   &   &  &   &   \\
          & x &   &  & x &   &  & x &   &  & x &   &  & x &   &  & x &   &  & x &   \\
method    & x & x &  & x & x &  & x & x &  & x & x &  & x & x &  & x & x &  & x & x \\
a         &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   \\
b         &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   \\
context   &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   \\
Ours      &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   \\
w/o clf   &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   \\
w/ GT clf &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   &  &   &   
\end{tblr}
}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: In general, remove all the empty columns (those with `& &` cells only) and use `\cmidrule` options here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462542/11604) to allow some space among header rules, but using `tblr` maybe better the equivalent syntax (tabulararray manual, page 13, second example)

Answer (score 0):

- as @Fran already mentioned in his comment, remove all empty columns. Instead them for rules below multicolumn cells use for example `\cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{2-3}`
- desired design of the first row is not entirely clear, so I hope that MWE below is correct.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l *{14}{X{c}} @{}},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=6}{c},
             cell{1}{10} = {c=6}{c},
             cell{2}{even[2]} = {c=2}{},
            }
    \toprule
            & x &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & x &   &   &   &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{2-7}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{10-15}
            & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   & x &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{2-3}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{6-7}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{8-9}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{10-11}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{12-13}
    \cmidrule[lr=-0.4]{14-15}
method      & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
    \midrule
a           &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
b           &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
context     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
Ours        &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
w/o clf     &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
w/ GT clf   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Kong, any news?